# How to routing and redirect when login on Laravel5.2.31

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel-5

I'm using laravel5.2.31.
I wanna make login cope and when User after login success, redirect to '/'.
And I can register cope but I can't login cope and cannot redirect to '/'.
I made auth by `php artisan make:auth` on terminal.
And my routes.php is

```
Route::post('auth/register','Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('auth/register','Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});
```

So I can see auth/login page on browser.
But I cannot post cope.
Now if I inport email and password and push login button,
So I redirected to my own login page.

How Can I do it?
What's the cause cannot it?

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 5.2.27 the web middleware is [applied by default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L56) and so you no longer need to specify it - so feel free to remove it from your routes.

As for the redirect, you can just add this to your `AuthController`:

`private $redirectTo = '/';`

This will redirect users to `/` after successful login or registration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My RouteServiceProvider.php map method is ``        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        }); `` There is no `` 'middleware' => 'web'. And add a 'middleware' => 'web' and remove one by route.php. So I meet this error `` Session store not set on request. ``

Comment: Yep - and so you can remove the `web` group middleware in your `routes.php` file